# Event fire again and again when use response method for export gridview to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

hello everybody
i am using c# .net in my webapplication.
i have a method for export gridview data to excel name ExportToExcel().
in this method i use response.contenttype, response.clear(),response.write(),stringwriter,htmltextwriter  methods.
this method work fine and export data correctly.
but when i write 
button1.visible = false above that method call then button does not unvisible. 
Means i write the following

button1.visible = false;    //   both not work on runtime
panel1.visible = false;     //
ExportToExcel()

another problem is that after call ExportToExcel() method if i click on any button on my webpage then ExportToExcel() again call and shows dialog box to save and open excel file.

so please help me how to solve this problem
I m unable to send code due to company rules so please help me

Thank to all in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your C# is rendering HTML elements and sending them to the client. HTML does not have a .visible property. You need to set correct HTML atributes or style rules before sending the element back to the client.

It sounds like you are calling ExportToExcel() after every postback. Have you checked that the you are only calling it when the ExportToExcel button is clicked?

Comment: ya i have checked i am calling it on button click. Please tell me how i set the property of button to visible false

Comment: The simplest way would be to use CSS. You will need to set the style properties of the button. In CSS you can set visibility:hidden or display:none. They do different things but both hide the element. Sorry if this is a bit vague but it has been a while since I worked on a .Net webapp.